# How do I get the public file URI for a media file from jsonapi?

Tags: media, uri

I have an audio file that is stored as Media of type Audio.

Now I want to get the link to that file that is usually displayed to site users via jsonapi.

For example, when the media entity is rendered, this is the link:

```
<audio controls="" controlslist="nodownload"> <source src="/sites/default/files/coolstuff/audio/apples-bananas-pears.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"> </audio>
```

This `/sites/default/files/coolstuff/audio/apples-bananas-pears.mp3` path is what I want to get from jsonapi.

However, when I look at the output of `/jsonapi/media/audio`, all the URLs look like this:

```
http://mysite.com/jsonapi/media/audio/d741b59c-9617-4a24-a2e8-99005a76507b?resourceVersion=id%3A31"
```

None of them have the public-facing URI.

[The documentation](https://www.drupal.org/docs/core-modules-and-themes/core-modules/jsonapi-module/fetching-resources-get#s-get-article-media-entity-reference-field-image-url-uri-by-including-references) gives this example for a "article media entity reference field_image url, uri by including references":

```
http://example.com/jsonapi/node/article/{{article_uuid}}?include=field_image&fields[file--file]=uri,url
```

I have media entity references, so I tried the same on my site:

```
http://mysite.com/jsonapi/node/MY_CONTENT_TYPE?include=field_ref_media_audio&fields[file--file]=uri,url
```

However, I do not get the regular media URI, just the jsonapi one.

How can I get the media public file URI (`/sites/default/files/coolstuff/audio/apples-bananas-pears.mp3`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the correct path:

```
http://mysite.com/jsonapi/node/MY_CONTENT_TYPE?include=field_ref_media_audio.field_media_audio_file&fields[file--file]=uri,url
```

This results in a value for `uri` such as:

```
"value": "public:/sites/default/files/coolstuff/audio/apples-bananas-pears.mp3",
```

Comment: are you aware of anyway to flatten this out a bit? This means my front-end needs to loop `included` for the `field_media.uuid`, then loop its `relationships` for the its `file--file.uuid`, then back up across `included` to find `file-file.attributes.uri.url`

Comment: @E.A.T No, I don't know a way to simplify this.  There is the JSON:API Resources module to define your own custom resource if you want to write all the logic yourself on the backend.